# Properties on a prototype being affected differently

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance, prototype-programming

I'm using prototype inheritance in this code snippet:

```js
function SuperType() {
  this.colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
  this.x = 1;
}

function SubType() {}
SubType.prototype = new SuperType();

var instance1 = new SubType();
instance1.colors.push("black");
instance1.x = 2;
//alert(instance1.colors); // "red,blue,green,black"
//alert(instance1.x); // 2

var instance2 = new SubType();
alert(instance2.colors); // "red,blue,green,black"
alert(instance2.x); // 1
```

I expect the output to be

```
"red,blue,green"
1
```

or

```
"red,blue,green,black"
2
```

but I get:

```
"red,blue,green,black"
1
```

Why?

Comment: you just created a new instance of `SubType`. Try 
`var instance2 = instance1`

Comment: arrays and objects are passed by reference, while for primitive types (string,numbers, etc.) the reference is the value , [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
instance1.x = 2;
```

you are adding a new property called `x` to `instance1`.

The prototype of `instance1`, which you can look up with [`instance1.__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), is  unaffected. The value of `instance1.__proto__.x` is still 1.

When you refer to

```
instance1.x
```

the object's own property `instance1.x` takes precedence over the prototype's property `instance1.__proto__.x`. We say that the `x` on `instance1` *shadows* the `x` on `instance1.__proto__`.

When JavaScript evaluates `instance1.x`, it checks the own properties of `instance1` before moving up the prototype chain. Therefore, the value of the own property `instance1.x` is what you see.

But when you write

```
instance1.colors
```

the object `instance1` does not have an own property called `colors`. Therefore, JavaScript looks at its prototype. It finds `instance1.__proto__.colors` and returns its current value.

When you wrote

```
instance1.colors.push("black");
```

you did not add a new property to `instance1`. You merely modified the array `instance1.__proto__.colors`. All objects that have the same prototype will see the same value of `colors` unless they have a property that shadows `colors`.

In the code snippet below, I have made a third object, `c`, that defines an own property called `colors`, which shadows the prototype's property `c.__proto__.colors`.

```
var c = new SubType();
c.colors = [ 'orange', 'purple' ];
```

The value of the own property `c.colors` is a different array than the prototype's property `c.__proto__.colors`. Objects that don't have an own property `colors` will continue to see the value of the prototype's `colors`.

```js
function SuperType() {
    this.colors = ["red", "blue", "green"];
    this.x = 1;
}
function SubType() {}
SubType.prototype = new SuperType();

var a = new SubType();
a.colors.push("black");
a.x = 2;
message('a.colors: ' + a.colors.join(', '));  // red, blue, green, black (prototype's colors)
message('a.x: ' + a.x);                       // 2 (own property x)
message('a.__proto__.x: ' + a.__proto__.x);   // 1 (prototype's x)

var b = new SubType();
message('b.colors: ' + b.colors.join(', '));  // red, blue, green, black (prototype's colors)
message('b.x: ' + b.x);                       // 1 (prototype's x)

var c = new SubType();
// Make an own property, colors, that shadows the prototype's property.
c.colors = [ 'orange', 'purple' ];
message('c.colors: ' + c.colors.join(', '));  // orange, purple (own property colors)
message('b.colors: ' + b.colors.join(', '));  // red, blue, green, black (prototype's colors)
message('a.colors: ' + a.colors.join(', '));  // red, blue, green, black (prototype's colors)


function message(line) {
  document.getElementById('messageBox').innerHTML += line + '<br>';
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="messageBox"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here:

```
SubType.prototype = new SuperType();
```

Because the `SuperType` constructor puts the `.colors` Array on the object, and because the object is used as the `.prototype` of `SubType`, that `.colors` Array is shared between all `SubType` instances.

Instead, don't invoke the constructor when setting up inheritance but *do* invoke it within the `SubType` constructor.

```
function SubType() {
    SuperType.apply(this, arguments);
}
SubType.prototype = Object.create(SuperType.prototype);
```

---

The reason the `.x` didn't have the same issue is that numbers are not mutable, so when you try to modify it, a new `x` gets created directly on the object you're using instead of mutating the `.prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `.push("black")` you are using a method that modifies the object (the list of colours) in place; so all variables pointing at that object see the change.

When you use `= 2`, you are replacing the value of that one variable, so other variables can still point at the original value.